# I have .htaccess rewrite rure which also rewrite folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my code:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?category=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)    index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2    [NC,L]
```

Now the problem is, It actually treats directory and subdirectory as category and sub-category respectively. I have tried many different solutions to leave directory untouched but none seem to work.

someone suggest me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

AND

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/digitalserp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
```

None works until now. Please suggest me the best way to make clean URL like http://www.example.com/category/sub-category without rewriting all the CSS, JS and Images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `END` instead of `L`. It prevents all further rewriting because Apache loops until it finds no further matching rules, or the looping gets terminated by hitting a limit. If you can't use `END` because your Apache is very old, then add `DPI` to your original rules so the path is not carried over to subsequent loops.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,B,QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/([A-Z0-9-]+)/? index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [NC,B,QSA,END]
```

Comment: Thanks my problem was actually resolved by this code:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


#Disable rewriting

RewriteEngine Off


</IfModule>`

I have put this code in the .htaccess and uploaded it in the css and js folder. I works now but will also try your idea to check the best way.

Thanks a lot @Walf

Comment: @PrashantRajpoot That doesn't make any sense; your solution to making rewriterules work was to completely disable rewriting?

Comment: Yeah, It is a temporary solution to disable rewrite in CSS and related folders alike. I will try your answer after I will start that project again. If it will work, I will also let you know.

Thanks for the help @Walf.

Comment: There is no need to use END in the rules as pattern and destination path of the rules are different. L is fine in this situation.

Comment: @starkeen You're making assumptions about the environment. Posters do not always give their entire `.htaccess` contents, and if such a simple rule is failing, it's usually because of interference from another. Besides, `END` is best practice for mapping a virtual URL to a file; `L`  should only be used where the URL may need further rewriting.